# Why is my app icon bigger than the others in the macOS dock?

Tags: macos

I just added an app icon to my project in SwiftUI-macOS. After building and running I see my app icon is bigger than it should be! Why does this happen? As you can see, it has no corner radius either.

[image]

Comment: Many MacOS icons allow "elements" to expand beyond the base bounds of the icon frame (look at Xcode and the simulators), so the "border" area is smaller or inset from the boundaries of the image itself.  For example, @512 I use an inset of 51 (so the "background" is 410px) and then I allow part of the "foreground" to expand into the empty space.  This is just a guide, I spent ages looking at the available templates, taking snapshots and just plain "guessing"

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Thanks for replaying, but I do not design for 512! I design for 1024 then build smaller ones for app icon online. So you mean I should have 1024 for start but design like for 900X900? and put borders clear? how about corner radius? Should I design that corners by myself in photoshop? seems trouble works.

Comment: Sure, but @512 was an example (because I had that one at hand), but the idea remains.  I can't say what percentage of the background should fill, I'm just going on guess work generally ;)

Comment: You might have a look at [Apple Design Resources](https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/) (look for MacOS)

Comment: I am looking to know the exact percentage of area when we are working on 1024X1024 also I need to know about the standard corner radius.

Answer (score 15):

I would suggest having a look at [Human Interface Guidelines/App Icons and images](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/icons-and-images/app-icon/) and [Apple Design Resources](https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/)

For example, this is one of the (Photoshop) templates which I based my designs off

[image]

As you can see, the "background" is inset from the edge of the image boundaries, which allows you to do things like...

[image]

Answer (score 8):

**Size** of **RoundedRectangular** for art design would be **(13/16) of  1024X1024** equal **832X832**

**CornerRadius** of **RoundedRectangular** would be **(22/100) of 832.0** or in other word would be **(22/100)X(13/16)X1024.0**

After making this image that its real size is **1024X1024** and the art size is **832X832**  we can build other smaller sizes for our Xcode macOS projects via online or offline icon maker.